# Android - Black Frame after dismissing Share Dialog

Tags: android

After dismissing a Share Dialog when i press back button there's a black frame that fills the screen and disappears after a second, any idea why this is happening and how to solve it ?

```
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, viewer.getUrl());
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```